PWM Universal Motor Control
I recently posted a question about a circuit I had that wasn't working, and received some feedback indicating that most of my circuit was just... not good.  Original post
I drew up a new schematic, but I wanted to post it here for any feedback before I go and start buying all of my parts like I had been doing before (and wasting a lot more money in the process).
I'm trying to control the universal motor with PWM from a microcontroller (either with an Arduino or what I'm currently working with, Adafruit Feather RP2040).  I went away from the Raspberry Pi because it didn't look like it could handle the frequency of my PWM, which I'm looking at 5kHz right now.  That frequency keeps me in the tp = 100μs PWM range.

Power supply is 24V
L7818CV is 18V Voltage Regulator
Motor rated for 5.75A
MOSFET Datasheet
Gate Driver Datasheet
Flyback Diode Datasheet
I tried to include as much info on the schematic as possible, but let me know if anything needs more clarification.
Should I use a logic-output optocoupler to drive the gate driver as was suggested in my previous post, or is a BJT sufficient?  Is there anything else that stands out here that I should be aware of?

If you're new to electronics, please may I gently suggest that you avoid working with mains voltages entirely...

Okay, well, I need to control the motor with mains voltages, so I'm not sure how else to approach this. Is there something you'd suggest I do differently?  For the record, I'm controlling it with 115.

C2 is critical for safety - it MUST be a Y rated capacitor!  U1 cannot be powered from your isolated power supply. You need a separate power supply for it. Currently your circuit is putting mains voltage onto the low voltage circuit. You’ve probably blown up  U1 as a consequence. You’ve made a number of decisions that have made your task unsafe.  In my part of the world there is no shortage of junked  exercise treadmills. These have a motor controller similar to what you want.  Get one of these and study how they do it. There’s also schematics on the web.

I haven't built this circuit yet, I was waiting for feedback. I was hoping to avoid having to use another power supply, but maybe it's inevitable?  I'll go back to the drawing board.  In my head, I was thinking the drive supply on the mosfet was isolated from the mains ground, but now I realize it isn't.

To be precise, the connection between pins 2 and 8 of U1 optocoupler is the critical problem.the opto must have a separate power supply to pins 5 and 8. There’s various ways to achieve this like using a ‘capacitive dropper’ but given your skill level, I’d not suggest you try this as this has significant danger associated with it.A small power transformer/rectifier/capacitor/regulator might be the simplest solution. You also chose a power supply module that requires specific knowlege to use correctly - why not just use a module that works out of the box?

Yeah, while I was drawing this up, I had it in my head that the drive supply would be isolated from the mains ground, but now I see that isn't true. What do you mean the power supply requires specific knowledge?

The power supply requires external components and proper pcb layout. You’ve also chosen a silicon carbide mosfet for U2 - way overkill for the application and very costly. Considering you’ll most likely blow one up, I suggest using a much cheaper device.

Google PF906 treadmill motor controller.   There’s YouTube vids and other info. This might help your design.

Do you mean C2?  I've replaced that part, but haven't rebuilt the circuit yet.  I realized that it was the wrong part, and I have a Y-rated cap ready to go.  Nothing is being built until I'm thoroughly convinced that my circuit is going to work this time.

Will do, thanks.

Overcurrent protection on the motor part of your circuit is recommended and possibly required based on where you live.

Are you just referring to a fuse or more than that?  The goal is to include a fuse right before the motor, and I'll go ahead and include it in my next revision.
